# Check pre-existence of macro name using a macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, directive

I have coded a header (.h) file with several includes and tens of macros. Before each macro I have coded this:

```
#if defined (MACRO_NAME)
#warning "Macro name MACRO_NAME is already in use. Please rename the macro"
#endif
```

It would be GREAT to have a macro that does all that checking stuff in order to increase readability of the code, but directives aren't allowed inside macros.

I would like something like that:

```
#define CHECK_MACRO_NAME(MACRO_NAME) \
    #if defined (MACRO_NAME) \
    #warning "Macro name "MACRO_NAME" is already in use. Please rename the macro" \
    #endif
```

Do you know any other (better) way of doing this?

Comment: I think your way is fine and readable enough.

Comment: Thank you :) There's no better solution, I guess...

Answer (score 5):

A better way might be just let your compiler do the checking.

```
/* test.c */

#define MACRO

#define MACRO 1
```

Compiling using `gcc`:

```
$ gcc -c test.c
test.c:3:0: warning: "MACRO" redefined [enabled by default]
test.c:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

Comment: The pity is that I am using a proprietary compiler that generates code for an old microcontroller that doesn't show this warning. Fortunately still supports the deprecated #warning directive. Thank you!